# verifying and inserting details into db

Tags: php

I need to insert the details (name, id , number )of many documents into database if they are not already existing and if they exist i just need to do a update for any changed information. I have arrived at the following code but it doesn't work. I am new to this and need help on this.

```
foreach($A->Documents -> Document as $Document)
 {
  $query = "SELECT * from table where id = '".$Document->id."'";

   $outcome = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
      if(($outcome)&&(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)){
       echo "Document already available" ;
         while($row = mysql_fetch_object($outcome)){
           if(!($outcome->name == $document->name)){
                  $update= "UPDATE table SET name= '.$Document->Name.'";
                  mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_error());
                  }
           else 
                  {
                  $insert= "INSERT table SET name= '.$Document->Name.'";
                  mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_error());
                  }

          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you got any error? or getting no result?

Comment: don't just spam all stackexchange forums... Your code doesn't work so put it on stackoverflow not on codereview or both...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

Use `$row->name` instead of `$outcome->name`. and your `INSERT` statement is wrong.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($outcome)){
  if(!($row->name == $document->name)){
    $update = "UPDATE table SET name ='".$Document->Name."' WHERE id = ".$Document->id;
    mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_error());
  }
  else {
    $insert = "INSERT INTO table (name) VALUES('".$Document->Name."')";
    mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error()); // $insert not $update
  }
}
```

> Note: Stop using `mysql_*` functions! Use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead. And use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_error());
```

To:

```
$insert = INSERT into table_name values(" values");
mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
```

in the else condition

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with **$result** variable with in if statement

( if(($outcome)&&(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)){)

It should be $outcome because you initialized query output to $outcome variable

Answer (score -1):

First of, dont yse mysql_ functions. Read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) (read the warning).
use mysqli or PDO instead.

Then, your INSERT statement is wrong.

```
INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES (value_for_col1);
```